# Inserting an image to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to insert a raster image or a pdf image underneath a `geom_line()` on a `ggplot2` plot?

I wanted to be quickly able to plot data over a previously calculated plot that takes a long time to generate as it uses a large amount of data.

I read through this [example](https://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/use-image-for-background-in-ggplot2/). However, as it is over one year old I thought there might be a different way of doing this now.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

try `?annotation_custom` in `ggplot2`

example,

```
library(png)
library(grid)
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)

qplot(1:10, 1:10, geom="blank") +
  annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Is it possible to read in an external file such as a `.jpg` or `.pdf` to use with `annotation_custom()' ? I read through some examples but the annotation seems to be generated in R.

Comment: i added an example for a bitmap. With a vector image, you'll need to create a grob with the `grImport` package.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if wanting to add two of the same image. How would one do this?

Comment: @kennyB for a reason I don't understand, the grobs need to have unique names. Try `g2 = editGrob(g, name="newgrob")`

Comment: Note that this does not work with `coord_polar`, but one can find a solution for that case at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496000/trying-to-add-an-image-to-a-polar-plot-gives-error-annotation-custom-only-work.

Comment: When I save the result image from above with ggsave(filename="plotwithr.png"), load it again with
img <- readPNG("plotwithr.png")
and then do the qplot again with this grob, why does it not cover the entire area and shrinks instead?

Answer (score 54):

Could also use the [`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html) R package (`cowplot` is a powerful extension of `ggplot2`). It will also need the [`magick`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/index.html) package. Check this [introduction to cowplot vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html).

Here is an example for both PNG and PDF background images.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(magick)

# Update 2020-04-15: 
# As of version 1.0.0, cowplot does not change the default ggplot2 theme anymore.
# So, either we add theme_cowplot() when we build the graph 
# (commented out in the example below), 
# or we set theme_set(theme_cowplot()) at the beginning of our script:
theme_set(theme_cowplot())

my_plot <- 
  ggplot(data    = iris, 
         mapping = aes(x    = Sepal.Length, 
                       fill = Species)) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.7) # +
  # theme_cowplot()

# Example with PNG (for fun, the OP's avatar - I love the raccoon)
ggdraw() +
  draw_image("https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDOo4.jpg?s=328&g=1") +
  draw_plot(my_plot)
```

[image]

```
# Example with PDF
ggdraw() +
  draw_image(file.path(R.home(), "doc", "html", "Rlogo.pdf")) +
  draw_plot(my_plot)
```

[image]

Also, as @seabass20 asked in the comment below, we can also give a custom position and scale to the image. Below is an example inspired from `help(draw_image)`. One needs to fine tune the parameters `x`, `y`, and `scale` until gets the desired output.

```r
logo_file <- system.file("extdata", "logo.png", package = "cowplot")
my_plot_2 <- ggdraw() +
  draw_image(logo_file,  x = 0.3, y = 0.4, scale = .2) +
  draw_plot(my_plot)
my_plot_2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to specify where the image should go (i.e. if I want the image just in the top-right corner of my plot)? Thanks!

Comment: @seabass20, Thanks for your comment. I made an extra example in my answer to accommodate your needs. You can always find more examples and details in `help(draw_image)`. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 27):

Just adding an update from the terrific Magick package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)
library(here) # For making the script run without a wd
library(magrittr) # For piping the logo

# Make a simple plot and save it
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("Cars") +
  ggsave(filename = paste0(here("/"), last_plot()$labels$title, ".png"),
         width = 5, height = 4, dpi = 300)

# Call back the plot
plot <- image_read(paste0(here("/"), "Cars.png"))
# And bring in a logo
logo_raw <- image_read("http://hexb.in/hexagons/ggplot2.png") 

# Scale down the logo and give it a border and annotation
# This is the cool part because you can do a lot to the image/logo before adding it
logo <- logo_raw %>%
  image_scale("100") %>% 
  image_background("grey", flatten = TRUE) %>%
  image_border("grey", "600x10") %>%
  image_annotate("Powered By R", color = "white", size = 30, 
                 location = "+10+50", gravity = "northeast")

# Stack them on top of each other
final_plot <- image_append(image_scale(c(plot, logo), "500"), stack = TRUE)
# And overwrite the plot without a logo
image_write(final_plot, paste0(here("/"), last_plot()$labels$title, ".png"))
```

[image: Cars with logo]

Answer (score 5):

Following up on @baptiste's answer, you don't need to load the grob package and convert the image if you use the more specific annotation function `annotation_raster()`.

That quicker option could look like this:

```r
# read picture
library(png)
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package = "png"))
# plot with picture as layer
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapping = aes(1:10, 1:10)) +
  annotation_raster(img, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: But you can't change the size of image in this way.

Comment: You can change the size of the image by changing the values in xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax