# How do you save a ggplot_table as a jpeg?

Tags: r, ggplot2, jpeg

Following Sandy Muspratt's answer to the question: ["Inserting an image to ggplot outside the chart area"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463691/inserting-an-image-to-ggplot-outside-the-chart-area), how would you save the output to a jpeg? This would be very helpful for generating reports in R.

Comment: Did you try `jpeg("plot_name.jpg"); myplot; dev.off()`?  If you are making reports `knitr` may be the way to go.

Comment: I did not.  I agree about knitr, based on what I have seen and the little I've read, but I'm trying to get this so that I could drop the report into a slide, a doc, etc.  (Also, currently, putting this plot into an R Shiny app; using knitr there is going to be great once I learn it).

Comment: I tried my suggestion and it works with the post you linked to.  knitr (and other tools like pandoc, slidify, RStudio, pander) can make a slide, a doc etc. except you drop nothing, it drops it for you.

Comment: Could you post your solution. It would be great to see how knitr would apply.  I do yet know how to employ knitr.  I think it would be great as well for others to see the diversity of the solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to create grobs, arrange them using `arrangeGrob` and use `ggsave`:

```
library(png)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
## create image grob
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)
## ggplot2 grob
p = qplot(x=x,y=y,data= data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10))
library(gridExtra)
## arrange and save 
ggsave('test.png', arrangeGrob(p,g))
```