# How to use .ico images in plots programmatically with/without conversion

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, lattice, ico

How to use `.ICO` image files in plots programmatically with/without conversion?

My question is a follow-up of [How to convert .ICO to .PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590/how-to-convert-ico-to-png), targeted to `R`, and with the following specific details:

- I am not asking about methods involving transcluding the icons within an `HTML`, e.g. inside a `shiny` app (author: RStudio). That is of course possible.
- Can the icons `.ICO` files be used directly in a base-R plot, a ggplot object (author: Hadley Wickham) , a lattice plot (author: Deepayan Sarkar)? And will this approach be robust to printing the output to `PDF`?
- How to convert the `ICO` icons to `PNG` with or without a dedicated `R` library. This method would be careful to handle the icon's image size, depth, transparency, and other potentially important properties.

The motivation for this is simply that there are many open-source libraries of icons that one could use inside plot objects, e.g. [Inserting an image to ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917049/inserting-an-image-to-ggplot2), [Display custom image as geom_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637455/display-custom-image-as-geom-point?lq=1), [Inserting an image to ggplot outside the chart area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463691/inserting-an-image-to-ggplot-outside-the-chart-area).

In the question I cite at the top, [How to convert .ICO to .PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590/how-to-convert-ico-to-png), there are examples of code in `C#` and in `Python`, but none in `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a `magick` package and you don't need to use `system` anymore:

```
library(magick)
path  <- "magic.png" # wherever you want to save
image <- image_read("https://rpubs.com/favicon.ico") # works with local path as well
```

In R studio, this will print our image in the plot window, for ico files it shows the different icons available in the file.

```
image
```

Then you can save in the desired format :

```
image_write(image,path,"png")
file.exists(path)
# [1] TRUE
```

There's [a really cool vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html):

Comment: At the time I looked, the vignette was as good as most packages' documentation!

Answer (score 2):

Install [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org) on your system (**your system** - its not an R package). Its a set of open source image manipulation and conversion tools.

From the command line you can then convert icons with `convert foo.ico foo.png`. If the ICO file contains multiple icons you get `foo-1.ico` to `foo-N.ico`. If `convert` doesn't work then you've not installed ImageMagick properly.

If you want to do this from R then use the `system` function:

```
 name = "foo"
 system(paste0("convert ",name,".ico ",name,".png"))
```

Then use the generated PNG files. They will preserve all the properties (transparency etc), and will be usable as much as any other PNG files are usable in those packages, which is outside the scope of this question. You now have your PNG files.

One **could** write an R package to read ICO files natively (the spec is on Wikipedia) but it seems a bit pointless when ImageMagick exists and does such a brilliant job. Use it.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The conversion is done by the ImageMagick "convert" command. Should work from R console or R Studio *if* ImageMagick is correctly installed. Have you tried it???

Comment: No I haven't tried it, as I only have access to a browser at present (!) I think I get it: the ``system()`` function acts like a command-line call, right? I could do something like this ``system("ls -la")``, could I? EDIT: yep, just tested on https://www.rollapp.com/.

Comment: I'll wait a little to see if anyone comes up with something else and if no-one does I will accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: fyi there's now a `magick` package on `CRAN`, see answer below