# ggplot Heatmap and Density Plot Errors

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, heatmap

This new post is in reference to a previous post ([Heatmap in a Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110646/heatmaps-on-physical-images-2d-or-3d-using-js-library-for-r-shiny-app/33112186#33112186)).

The sample dataset is found here: [Sample Dataset used in the Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11I19uQyND7YehKrYd-NPiib4bQSHmHmWENFvausigvU/edit?usp=sharing)

The resulting density plot and the plot showing the maximum values in the dataset for each position do not seem to match up.  The third `ggplot` has a few issues that I am unsure how to fix.

- I set the scale of the third `ggplot` in `scale_fill_gradientn` for 0 to 100.  However, the heatmap colors of the resulting plot are not the same color as what the scale should show.  For example, the `94.251` should be a darker organge, but it doesn't appear on the chart.
- Some of the text for the Max Values in the third `ggplot` are not matched up to the rectangles of coordinate locations.  I am looking to fix this issue.
- I would also like the density plot in the first `ggplot` to show a blend, similar to the blend that is shown in this sample density plot.  I'm not really sure how to do that:

[image]

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)


sensor.data <- read.csv("Sample_Dataset.csv") 

# Create position -> coord conversion 
pos.names <- names(sensor.data)[ grep("*Pos",names(sensor.data)) ] # Get column names with "Pos" in them 
mock.coords <<- list() 
lapply(pos.names, function(name){ 
  }) 
mock.coords <- list ("Position1"=data.frame("x"=0.1,"y"=0.2), 
                     "Position2"=data.frame("x"=0.2,"y"=0.4), 
                     "Position3"=data.frame("x"=0.3,"y"=0.6), 
                     "Position4"=data.frame("x"=0.4,"y"=0.65), 
                     "Position5"=data.frame("x"=0.5,"y"=0.75), 
                     "Position6"=data.frame("x"=0.6,"y"=0.6), 
                     "Position7"=data.frame("x"=0.7,"y"=0.6), 
                     "Position8"=data.frame("x"=0.8,"y"=0.43), 
                     "Position9"=data.frame("x"=0.9,"y"=0.27), 
                     "Position10"=data.frame("x"=0.75,"y"=0.12))

# Change format of your data matrix 
df.l <- list() 
cnt <- 1 

for (i in 1:nrow(sensor.data)){ 
  for (j in 1:length(pos.names)){ 
    name <- pos.names[j] 
    curr.coords <- mock.coords[[name]] 
    df.l[[cnt]] <- data.frame("x.pos"=curr.coords$x, 
                              "y.pos"=curr.coords$y, 
                              "heat" =sensor.data[i,j]) 
    cnt <- cnt + 1 
  } 
} 

df <- do.call(rbind, df.l) 


# Load image 
    library(jpeg)
download.file("http://www.expresspcb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/PhotoProductionPCB_TL_800.jpg","pcb.jpg")
img <- readJPEG("/home/oskar/pcb.jpg")

g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE,width=1,height=1) 

# Show overlay of image and heatmap 
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x.pos,y=y.pos,fill=heat)) + 
  annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) + 
  stat_density2d( alpha=0.2,aes(fill = ..level..), geom="polygon" ) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev( rainbow(3) )) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  ggtitle("Density") 


# # Show where max temperature is 
# dat.max = df[which.max(df$heat),] 
# 
# ggplot(data=coords,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
#   annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) + 
#   geom_point(data=dat.max,aes(x=x.pos,y=y.pos), shape=21,size=5,color="black",fill="red") + 
#   geom_text(data=dat.max,aes(x=x.pos,y=y.pos,label=round(heat,3)),vjust=-1,color="red",size=10) + 
#   ggtitle("Max Temp Position") 

# bin data manually 

# Manually set number of rows and columns in the matrix containing sums of heat for each square in grid 
nrows <- 30 
ncols <- 30 

# Define image coordinate ranges 
x.range <- c(0,1) # x-coord range 
y.range <- c(0,1) # x-coord range 

# Create matrix and set all entries to 0 
heat.density.dat <- matrix(nrow=nrows,ncol=ncols) 
heat.density.dat[is.na(heat.density.dat)] <- 0 

# Subdivide the coordinate ranges to n+1 values so that i-1,i gives a segments start and stop coordinates 
x.seg <- seq(from=min(x.range),to=max(x.range),length.out=ncols+1) 
y.seg <- seq(from=min(y.range),to=max(y.range),length.out=nrows+1) 

# List to hold found values 
a <- list() 
cnt <- 1 
for( ri in 2:(nrows+1)){ 
  x.vals <- x.seg [c(ri-1,ri)] 

  for ( ci in 2:(ncols+1)){ 
    # Get current segments, for example x.vals = [0.2, 0.3] 
    y.vals <- y.seg [c(ci-1,ci)] 

    # Find which of the entries in the data.frame that has x or y coordinates in the current grid 
    x.inds <- which( ( (df$x.pos >= min(x.vals)) & (df$x.pos <= max(x.vals)))==T ) 
    y.inds <- which( ((df$y.pos >= min(y.vals)) & (df$y.pos <= max(y.vals)))==T ) 

    # Find which entries has both x and y in current grid 
    inds <- intersect( x.inds , y.inds ) 

    # If there's any such coordinates 
    if (length(inds) > 0){ 
      # Append to list 
      a[[cnt]] <- data.frame("x.start"=min(x.vals), "x.stop"=max(x.vals), 
                             "y.start"=min(y.vals), "y.stop"=max(y.vals), 
                             "acc.heat"=sum(df$heat[inds],na.rm = T) ) 
      print(length(df$heat[inds])) 
      # Increment counter variable 
      cnt <- cnt + 1 
    } 
  } 
} 

# Construct data.frame from list 
heat.dens.df <- do.call(rbind,a) 

# Plot again 
ggplot(data=heat.dens.df,aes(x=x.start,y=y.start)) + 
  annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) + 
  geom_rect(data=heat.dens.df, aes(xmin=x.start, xmax=x.stop, ymin=y.start, ymax=y.stop, fill=acc.heat), alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev( rainbow(3) )) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))

mock.coords <- list ("Position1"=data.frame("x"=0.1,"y"=0.2), 
                     "Position2"=data.frame("x"=0.2,"y"=0.4), 
                     "Position3"=data.frame("x"=0.3,"y"=0.6), 
                     "Position4"=data.frame("x"=0.4,"y"=0.65), 
                     "Position5"=data.frame("x"=0.5,"y"=0.75), 
                     "Position6"=data.frame("x"=0.6,"y"=0.6), 
                     "Position7"=data.frame("x"=0.7,"y"=0.6), 
                     "Position8"=data.frame("x"=0.8,"y"=0.43), 
                     "Position9"=data.frame("x"=0.9,"y"=0.27), 
                     "Position10"=data.frame("x"=0.75,"y"=0.12)) 

# Show where max temperature is 
heat.dat <- sensor.data[pos.names] 

# Get max for each position 
max.df <- apply(heat.dat,2,max) 
dat.max.l <- lapply(1:length(max.df), function(i){ 
  h.val <- max.df[i] 
  c.name <- names(h.val) 
  c.coords <- mock.coords[[c.name]] 
  data.frame("x.pos"=c.coords$x, "y.pos"=c.coords$y,"heat"=h.val) 
}) 

coords <- data.frame("x"=c(0,1),"y"=c(0,1)) 
dat.max <- do.call(rbind,dat.max.l) 

ggplot(data=coords,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) + 
  geom_point(data=dat.max,aes(x=x.pos,y=y.pos), shape=13,size=5,color="black",fill="red") + 
  geom_text(data=dat.max,aes(x=x.pos,y=y.pos,label=round(heat,3)),vjust=-1,color="red",size=10) + 
  geom_rect(data=heat.dens.df, aes(xmin=x.start, xmax=x.stop, ymin=y.start, ymax=y.stop, fill=acc.heat,x=NULL,y=NULL), alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(0,100), colours = rev( rainbow(3) )) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

- To center the text, remove the `vjust` value in geom_text
- In order to create a heatmap for this data we need some type of interpolation or smoothing since you only have data for 10 points (or you'll have a heatmap with just a few datapoints)

This could be a solution:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)


sensor.data <- read.csv("/home/oskar/Downloads/Sample_Dataset.csv - Sample_Dataset.csv.csv") 

# Create position -> coord conversion 
pos.names <- names(sensor.data)[ grep("*Pos",names(sensor.data)) ] # Get column names with "Pos" in them 
mock.coords <- list ("Position1"=data.frame("x"=0.1,"y"=0.2), 
                     "Position2"=data.frame("x"=0.2,"y"=0.4), 
                     "Position3"=data.frame("x"=0.3,"y"=0.6), 
                     "Position4"=data.frame("x"=0.4,"y"=0.65), 
                     "Position5"=data.frame("x"=0.5,"y"=0.75), 
                     "Position6"=data.frame("x"=0.6,"y"=0.6), 
                     "Position7"=data.frame("x"=0.7,"y"=0.6), 
                     "Position8"=data.frame("x"=0.8,"y"=0.43), 
                     "Position8.1"=data.frame("x"=0.85,"y"=0.49), 
                     "Position9"=data.frame("x"=0.9,"y"=0.27), 
                     "Position10"=data.frame("x"=0.75,"y"=0.12))

# Change format of your data matrix 
df.l <- list() 
cnt <- 1 

for (i in 1:nrow(sensor.data)){ 
  for (j in 1:length(pos.names)){ 
    name <- pos.names[j] 
    curr.coords <- mock.coords[[name]] 
    df.l[[cnt]] <- data.frame("x.pos"=curr.coords$x, 
                              "y.pos"=curr.coords$y, 
                              "heat" =sensor.data[i,j]) 
    cnt <- cnt + 1 
  } 
} 

df <- do.call(rbind, df.l) 

# Load image 
library(jpeg)
download.file("http://www.expresspcb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/PhotoProductionPCB_TL_800.jpg","pcb.jpg")
img <- readJPEG("/home/oskar/pcb.jpg")
g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE,width=1,height=1) 

# Manually set number of rows and columns in the matrix containing max of heat for each square in grid
nrows <- 50
ncols <- 50

# Define image coordinate ranges
x.range <- c(0,1) # x-coord range
y.range <- c(0,1) # x-coord range

x.bounds <- seq(from=min(x.range),to=max(x.range),length.out = ncols + 1)
y.bounds <- seq(from=min(y.range),to=max(y.range),length.out = nrows + 1)

# Create matrix and set all entries to 0
heat.max.dat <<- matrix(nrow=nrows,ncol=ncols)

lapply(1:length(mock.coords), function(i){
  c <- mock.coords[[i]]
  # calculate where in matrix this fits
  x <- c$x; y <- c$y
  x.ind <- findInterval(x, x.bounds)
  y.ind <- findInterval(y, y.bounds)
  heat.max.dat[x.ind,y.ind] <<- max(sensor.data[names(mock.coords)[i]])
})
heat.max.dat[is.na(heat.max.dat)]<-0

require(fields)
# Look at the image plots to see how the smoothing works
#image(heat.max.dat)
h.mat.interp <- image.smooth(heat.max.dat)
#image(h.mat.interp$z)

mat <- h.mat.interp$z

require(reshape2)
m.dat <- melt(mat)
# Change to propper coors, image is assumed to have coors between 0-1
m.dat$Var1 <-  seq(from=min(x.range),to=max(x.range),length.out=ncols)[m.dat$Var1]
m.dat$Var2 <-  seq(from=min(y.range),to=max(y.range),length.out=ncols)[m.dat$Var2]

# Show where max temperature is 
heat.dat <- sensor.data[pos.names] 

# Get max for each position 
max.df <- apply(heat.dat,2,max) 
dat.max.l <- lapply(1:length(max.df), function(i){ 
  h.val <- max.df[i] 
  c.name <- names(h.val) 
  c.coords <- mock.coords[[c.name]] 
  data.frame("x.pos"=c.coords$x, "y.pos"=c.coords$y,"heat"=h.val) 
}) 

dat.max <- do.call(rbind,dat.max.l) 

coords <- data.frame("x"=c(0,1),"y"=c(0,1)) 
ggplot(data=coords,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
  geom_raster(data=m.dat,aes(x=Var1,y=Var2,fill=value), interpolate = TRUE, alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev( rainbow(3) ),guide=FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=dat.max,aes(x=x.pos,y=y.pos,label=round(heat,3)),vjust=0,color="white",size=5) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

In the end I get this
[image]

Comment: Oskar, thanks so much for this response.  Inside of the `ggplot` function call, can I somehow add a text label above each of the displayed values?

Comment: Yes, you can either calculate the coordinates and append them to the dataframe or you can just add another geom_text with same coordinates but with a vjust value of 1

Comment: I'm trying: 
  `geom_text(data=pos.names, aes(x=x.pos,y=y.pos,label=round(heat,3)),vjust=0,color="white",size=5)`  but to no avail.  It says ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character

Comment: You have to supply the coordinates as numeric values, for instance if I wanted to add a label for each position I would do:

Comment: coords2        <- do.call(rbind, mock.coords)
coords2$labels <- names(mock.coords)

ggplot(data=coords,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
  geom_raster(data=m.dat,aes(x=Var1,y=Var2,fill=value), interpolate = TRUE, alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev( rainbow(3) ),guide=FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=coords2,aes(x=x,y=y,label=labels),vjust=-1,color="white",size=5) +
  geom_text(data=dat.max,aes(x=x.pos,y=y.pos,label=round(heat,3)),vjust=0,color="white",size=5) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))

Comment: Nice!  Thanks Oskar!  How can I add a legend off to the right or left side of the chart?

Comment: Depending on what you want to have in your legend, see [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/) titles are added using ggtitle

Comment: Hi Oskar, in some of my data I have locations that are not visible on the PCB Image.  Say, for example, I have Positions 11-15 not on the image, how could I show a list of them with their temperature and color relative to Positions 1-10?  Perhaps, next to the image, Positions 11-15 could be in a table with their temps and color?

Comment: Put the data in a data.frame and use the `tableGrob` function from gridExtra, see `plot(tableGrob(head(iris)))`. The put the grobs together with grid.arrange. A example: g <- tableGrob(head(iris)); grid.arrange(g,g).

Comment: Hi Oskar, I recently posted a new question for the heatmap application.  I am now trying to link up my heatmap file with a dataset that I choose from a `selectInput` function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639556/how-could-i-adjust-a-ggplot-heatmap-based-on-the-column-values-from-a-reactive-s

Comment: I think my main issue is that when I load the image into my Shiny App with different names in `mock.coords`, it gives me the errors I described in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654240/undefined-columns-selected-when-doing-a-grep-on-column-names

What I want to do is be able to load ANY dataset into the `heatmap.R` script, and have it show up on the heatmap.  But some datasets have some of the column names and some do not.  I want to pre-set the locations in `heatmap.R`, and if those columns are in the loaded dataset, then those are the ones that get plotted.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, could you edit the question to make it more general? I think it will be easier to answer (with less work required) if you generalize it a bit but the column name to dataset matching should be easie

Comment: Thanks Oskar!  Which question would you like to be more general, the first or second one that I posted?

Comment: Update `Undefined columns selected when doing a grep on column names`, I think I can answer the other question as is when I have more time  although the more general the easier it is for others to answer too

Comment: Thanks @Oskar Forsmo!

Comment: And let me know if you need anything clarified!  Thanks @oskar!

Comment: Hi @Oskar Forsmo, are you able to support me with this, this week?

Comment: Hi Oskar, have you been able to look at this yet?

Comment: Sorry I've been really busy, I'll try to have a look at it this weekend

Comment: Hey Oskar, hope all is good.  Have you had a chance to look at this?