# How to annotate a ggplot2 plot with a double dagger symbol?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to use a [double dagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography)) symbol in a ggplot2 plot? Can I achieve this with the annotate() function?

Comment: Please see the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917049/inserting-an-image-to-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.

```
ggplot() + geom_blank() +
  annotate("text", x = 1, y = 1, label = "‡")
```