# How to save an 'AI friendly' plot in R when using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

When I save a tSNE plot with a large amount of points, I want to convert all the points in the plot to a PNG file while the remainder of the image (axes, labels, all text) remain as vector graphics. How could I do such things?

(I know that the Dimplot function in Seurat package can do this with parameter vector.friendly = TRUE)

Comment: Not sure if there is a ready tool for this, but we could output plot without axis as png image, then plot blank ggplot, then [add saved image to the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917049).

Comment: This is what `seurat::dimplot` is doing, too, see [GitHub - L2450](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/blob/65b77a9480281ef9ab1aa8816f7c781752092c18/R/plotting.R#L2450) and see [AugmentPlot function](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/blob/7618ac8798e2aefc509529f07af9d2836b96a1be/R/plotting_utilities.R#L312).

Comment: Any reason why dimplot is not an option?

Comment: Thank you, I think that plot ggplot with axis and text and then add a png image might be the best choice. The reason that not to use dimplot is that dimplot only use seurat object as an input, I want to avoid this.