# Need to show the country flag

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset where energy production is represented in 2 facets. I want to show the flag of the relevant country at the end of each geom line and to the legend next to the country name.

Is there any way that I can fix this issue?

```
library(tidyverse) #install.packages("tidyverse)
library(tidymodels) #install.packages("tidymodels")
library(skimr)  #install.packages("skimr")
library(ggplot2)  #install.packages("ggplot2")
library(dplyr)  ##install.packages("deplyr")
library(knitr)  #install.packages("knitr")
library(tidyr)  #install.packages("tidyr")
library(viridis) #install.packages("viridis")
devtools::install_github("rensa/ggflags") #install.packages("devtools")
library(ggflags)

ggplot(categ_top10EnergyModf,
       aes(x = factor(year),
           y = ggwt_hours,
           color = country_name,
           group = country_name)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_flag(country = country_name) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ type2, scale = 'free') +
  labs(x = "Year", 
       y = "Energy Production (GWh)",
       title = "Analysis of the growth of Renewable/Non-Renewable Energy production", 
       fill  = "Country", 
       color = "Country") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_grey()
```

```
> dput(head(categ_top10EnergyModf))
structure(list(country = c("DE", "DE", "FR", "FR", "FR", "DE"
), country_name = c("Germany", "Germany", "France", "France", 
"France", "Germany"), type2 = c("Non-Renewable", "Non-Renewable", 
"Non-Renewable", "Non-Renewable", "Non-Renewable", "Non-Renewable"
), year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L, 2018L), ggwt_hours = c(471984, 
449906, 448690.614, 447109.694, 445175.494, 393234.585)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(country = c("DE", "DE", "DE", "FR", 
"FR", "FR"), country_name = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"France", "France", "France"), year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2018L), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 
    3L, 4L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi dly! Please share a reproducible example

Comment: We need to be able to run your code. you need to provide some of your data. the easiear way is to share the output ot `dput(categ_top10EnergyModf)` or at least `dput(head(categ_top10EnergyModf))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9917049/1412059

Comment: add the libraries you're using.

Comment: @Edo: Updated the issue with the libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this?

You need to use `tolower(country)` to detect the name of the country.
To have one unique legend you need to set the same name in `colour` and `country` in `labs`.

I noticed you set a setting for `theme`, but to make it work you need to set it after `theme_gray`, otherwise it gets overwritten.

To set the flags just at the end you need to set `x` and `y` in `aes` of `geom_flag` to be equal only to the last point. That's what the `dplyr` pipeline is for at the beginning.

With your full dataset, the visualization should be better.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggflags)

categ_top10EnergyModf %>%
 mutate(year = factor(year),
        country = tolower(country)) %>% 
 group_by(type2, country) %>% 
 mutate(country_x = max(levels(year)),
        country_y = ggwt_hours[country_x == year]) %>% 
 
 ggplot(aes(x = year,
            y = ggwt_hours,
            color = country,
            group = country)) +
 geom_line(size = 1.5) +
 geom_point(size = 3) +
 geom_flag(aes(x = country_x, 
               y = country_y, 
               country = country)) +
 scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
 facet_wrap(. ~ type2, scale = 'free') +
 labs(x = "Year", 
      y = "Energy Production (GWh)",
      title = "Analysis of the growth of Renewable/Non-Renewable Energy production", 
      country = "Country", 
      color   = "Country") +
 theme_grey() +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
 scale_country()
```

[image]

Comment: Edo, thank you for the answer. I tried but I'm getting this error. 

    Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
      unable to find an inherited method for function ‘grobify’ for signature ‘"NULL"’

Comment: use country not country_name

Comment: I used the country but it works without scale_country().when I add scale_country(), the above issue throws because UK flag is missing. So flags are not coming for the legend

Comment: because `uk` needs to be `gb` to be recognized by `geom_flag`. add this at the beginning of your pipeline: `mutate(country = if_else(country == "UK", "GB", country))`

Comment: check out rensa's github page to learn all the accepted names: https://github.com/rensa/ggflags