When combining large patchwork plot, the plot overlapped
I have two large patchwork plots ht.plot1 and ht.plot2:

and this is the ht.plot1:

this is ht.plot2:

I have to view them in Rstudio Zoom, otherwise it is like this:

When I combine them:
ht.plot1 + ht.plot2

the output plot overlaped even I using Rstudio zoom to view it:

I also try to use plot_grid in cowplot package:
plot_grid(ht.plot1, ht.plot2, nrow = 2)

Howerver, it doesn't work, the output plot still overlap.
I think the cause of this problem is that the plot is too large. Am i right? Is there any methods to combine them?

Could you save the two plots as image files and combine them manually, for instance, using a presentation program? This would also allow to store the combined image as single image file.

@GRowInG Certainly, I can manually combine them. But it may be time consuming.

Did you try ht.plot1/ht.plot2 using the patchwork package? However, this package requires ggplot objects. If your plots are not, there are still ways to get there. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9917049/11809780
